# How to enable dragging of installer in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to click anywhere on the installer and be able to drag it across the window as long as the left button of the mouse is down.
The dragging should be just like the when you drag the installer by its top border.

Comment: That code doesn't work, they even say so in the comments

Comment: But your question is duplicate anyway. And their conclusion is that it's definitely not possible with core Inno Setup; and maybe possible using some external library, but no one has succeeded yet.